# Session Renegotiation Check

Tags: ssl

I'm writing some program in Java, which should check if the SSL Session Renegotiation is enabled or not in specific site.

I opened some handshake with the site, and don't know how to check the Session Renegotiation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create and connect an SSLSocket to the site.
2. Call startHandshake().
3. Get the SSLSession.
4. Call startHandshake() again.
5. Get the SSLSession again.

If the sessions at 3 and 5 are equal (same session ID), session resumption occurred.

Comment: Can you please help me with that?
I'm not sure about the methods.

Comment: SSLSocket.startHandshake(), SSLSocket.getSession() and SSLSession.getId(). See the Javadoc.